# How to add to top of list and if same just one time through database?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Hi Stackoverflow members i created an app where user can add favorite items to the favorite list. but the problem i am facing is that when i click on add to favorite button, the item adds to the bottom of the list and not on the top.

Second when i click the same item add to favorite item many time, this add the item multiple time and not just only one time. how can i add it to the list just only one time and not multiple time.
here is my code for activity and database.

My DBAdapter.class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


// TO USE:
// Change the package (at top) to match your project.
// Search for "TODO", and make the appropriate changes.
public class DBAdapter {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Constants & Data
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // For logging:
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    // DB Fields
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
    /*
     * CHANGE 1:
     */
    // TODO: Setup your fields here:
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_STUDENTNUM = "studentnum";
    public static final String KEY_FAVCOLOUR = "favcolour";

    // TODO: Setup your field numbers here (0 = KEY_ROWID, 1=...)
    public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
    public static final int COL_STUDENTNUM = 2;
    public static final int COL_FAVCOLOUR = 3;


    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_STUDENTNUM, KEY_FAVCOLOUR};

    // DB info: it's name, and the table we are using (just one).
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
    // Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;   

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
            + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            /*
             * CHANGE 2:
             */
            // TODO: Place your fields here!
            // + KEY_{...} + " {type} not null"
            //  - Key is the column name you created above.
            //  - {type} is one of: text, integer, real, blob
            //      (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
            //  - "not null" means it is a required field (must be given a value).
            // NOTE: All must be comma separated (end of line!) Last one must have NO comma!!
            + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
            + KEY_STUDENTNUM + " integer not null, "
            + KEY_FAVCOLOUR + " string not null"

            // Rest  of creation:
            + ");";

    // Context of application who uses us.
    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Public methods:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Open the database connection.
    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close the database connection.
    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Add a new set of values to the database.
    public long insertRow(String name, int studentNum, String favColour) {
        /*
         * CHANGE 3:
         */     
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_STUDENTNUM, studentNum);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FAVCOLOUR, favColour);

        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    // Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    // Return all data in the database.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, int studentNum, String favColour) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

        /*
         * CHANGE 4:
         */
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        newValues.put(KEY_STUDENTNUM, studentNum);
        newValues.put(KEY_FAVCOLOUR, favColour);

        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Private Helper Classes:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
     * Used to handle low-level database access.
     */
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

My favorite list activity..

```
DBAdapter myDb;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favoritediseases);

        openDB();
        populateListViewFromDB();
        registerListClickCallback();


         // this code is used for the action bar color change//
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
           bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#6B8E23")));
           getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  
        closeDB();
    }

    private void openDB() {
        myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
        myDb.open();
    }
    private void closeDB() {
        myDb.close();
    }

    /* 
     * UI Button Callbacks
     */



    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
                {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_STUDENTNUM};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                {R.id.item_name};

        // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,       // Context
                        R.layout.item_layout,   // Row layout template
                        cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                        fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                        toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                        );

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favlistView1);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }

    private void registerListClickCallback() {
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favlistView1);



        //This code is for to delete the single item from the listview of favorite list
        myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, final long arg3) {
                Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(arg3);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                        new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteDiseases.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete Item")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete this disease?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                // continue with delete
                                myDb.deleteRow(arg3);
                                populateListViewFromDB();
                        }
                     })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                            // do nothing
                        }
                     })
                     .show();            
    }
                return true;

            }

        });



        //this is the code used from starting activity from the favorite list database.
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, 
                    int position, long idInDB) {

                Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(idInDB);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    String name = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_NAME);
                    if (name.equals("Atherosclerosis")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,Atherosclerosis.class));
                    }else if
                     (name.equals("Coronary Heart Disease")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,CoronaryHeartDisease.class));
                    }else if (name.equals("Stable Angina")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,StableAngina.class));
                    }else if (name.equals("Acute Coronary Syndrome")){
                            startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,AcuteCoronarySyndrome.class));
                    }else if (name.equals("Myocardial Infarction")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,MyocardialInfarction.class));
                    }else if (name.equals("Unstable Angina")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,UnstableAngina.class));
                    }else if (name.equals("Acute Heart Failure")){
                    startActivity(new Intent(FavoriteDiseases.this,AcuteHeartFailure.class));
                }

                }
                cursor.close();
                updateItemForId(idInDB);
            }   
            });}



    private void updateItemForId(long idInDB) {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(idInDB);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.getLong(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
            String name = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_NAME);
            int studentNum = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_STUDENTNUM);
            String favColour = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_FAVCOLOUR);

            favColour += "!";
            myDb.updateRow(idInDB, name, studentNum, favColour);
        }
        cursor.close();
        populateListViewFromDB();       
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorite_diseases, menu);

        return true;
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Take appropriate action for each action item click
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_clear:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Delete List")
                .setMessage("Do you want to clear all?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // continue with delete
                        myDb.deleteAll();
                        populateListViewFromDB();
                    }
                 })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // do nothing
                    }
                 })

                 .show();

             return true;
}
        return true;
     }}
```

the final code from where i adding to the list

```
case R.id.id_favorit:
// Add it to the DB and re-draw the ListView
                myDb.insertRow("Atherosclerosis", 0, "");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Added to Favorite List!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                favClicked=true;

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
               return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just want to get your results from the DB in reverse order. Changing the function that retrieves them to ORDER BY your rowid in descending order will do the trick:

```
// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID + " DESC", null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Regarding your second question, you should check if the favorite exists before inserting it. The question is how you define your uniqueness. For example, if you don't want two "favorites" with the same name, you'll want to add a check in your insert function:

```
// Add a new set of values to the database, unless the name already exists.
public long insertRow(String name, int studentNum, String favColour) {
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    c.close();

    /*
     * CHANGE 3:
     */     
    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STUDENTNUM, studentNum);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FAVCOLOUR, favColour);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much gonna try this...please also look at my second question of highlighting a text in a simple linear layout.